# Create a new column that shows the occurence number of item in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a column that look like this

```
Name 
A
A
B
B
C
```

I want to append a column to this dataframe where it contains the occurrence number of the item in Name

```
Name  New_Column
A     1
A     2
B     1
B     2
C     1
```

So far, I can just turn Name column into a list, then loop over it and create the new_column, but is there a more straightforward way to do this directly in pandas?

Comment: `df.assign(New_Column=df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1)` Looking for dup.

Comment: thank you @piRSquared, it works, if you want, you can leave an answer and I can mark it as accepted

Comment: Thx @Jason I know this is a duplicate question.  I'm going to find it and mark it as such.  It is what we're supposed to do anyway (-:

Comment: I'll close it if I find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `groupby` and `cumcount`

`cumcount`s sole purpose is to increment each group separately.  If you add one to the result and assign it as a new column:

```
df.assign(New_Column=df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1)

  Name  New_Column
0    A           1
1    A           2
2    B           1
3    B           2
4    C           1
```